# fb share button not displayed with ajax file

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I used the following script in my web page

In body tag i used the following code

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

In my blog listing I used the following in each blog:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://test.com" data-layout="button"></div>
```

Its displayed fine. After 10 blogs while scroll the remaining data are loaded dynamically by using the ajax file.

Here also I used the above `script`  and `Div share button`. But it is not displayed with the ajax loaded file.

I googled a lot and I couldn't find a right solution. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after ajax, call function FB.XFBML.parse(); to force the refresh/rendering FB share buttons

Comment: I also used this fb share in bootstrap modal. The modal content is loaded on run time using <a data-toggle="modal" href="modal.php" data-target="#splModal">popup here</a>

I used the following script $('#splModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
 alert('aa');
 FB.XFBML.parse(); 
})
But fb share not displayed. Please help me

Comment: try FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('splModal'));